# How to change the owneship of default.conf file in code::blocks editor in ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, code-blocks

I just started using `code::blocks` editor and found that its default font size is smaller to me.Whenever I open it I have to manually resize the font by `settings -> editor -> choose`. I'm finding a way to make my customised settings as default.

[image]

I have searched about it all over the internet but didn't find a solution. I somewhere read that basic settings are stored in a file named `default.conf` which is only readable and only `root` has permission to edit it. How can I change its permission to make it writeable or some other way .So, can somebody please help me how can I make my customized settings as default. I'm in desperate need.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, you can edit the file as a sudoer by typing the command:

```
sudo vim /path/to/default.conf
```

I would recommend this method rather than below because changing the permissions could cause problems with code::blocks.

But, if you really want to change the owner and permissions of the file try:

```
sudo chown username:usergroup /path/to/default.conf
sudo chmod 666 /path/to/default.conf
```

[Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions) is a good read.